# My MacBook Pro MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5 Beta (17F66a) shuts down very time I close my lap top

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5 Beta (17F66a)  shuts down very time I close my lap top